# Syntax jQuery for contains test

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, contains

I want to test if my table have rows with two contains. I have tested this but it does not work:

```
$("#resultat tr:not(:contains("+$('.devoirs option:selected ').text()+"))","#resultat tr:not(:contains("+$('.formateur option:selected ').text()+"))").each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `:not()` doesn't support *true* pseudo selectors and `:contains` is jQuery specififc.

You might want to use explicit `.not()`.

```
$('#resultat tr').not(':contains("'+$('.devoirs option:selected ').text()+'")')
.end().not(':contains("'+$('.formateur option:selected ').text()+'")').each(function(){
    // do something 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the .not() but code doesn't work when i have two contains whith one it works perfectly.

Thanks